# Clear comboBox of one radioButton when another radioButton is activated

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, radio-button

I have two RadioButtons and one comboBox inside first radioButton and one textbox inside another radioButton.

When I activate first RadioButton, the corresponding ComboBox, it gets enabled. Now when I choose another RadioButton, the information in the previously selected ComboBox should clear but its not getting cleared.
Same is the case with textbox.

I am using c# language and visual studio 2013 version for this wpf application.

For loading drives names from FileExplorer in comboBox, I used this code-

```
DriveInfo[] listDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (DriveInfo drive in listDrives)
            {
                cmbDrives.Items.Add(drive.Name);
            }
```

here cmbDrives is the name of comboBox

I tried this code-

```
if (radioButton1.IsChecked == true)
            {
                textBox.Text = "";
            }

if (radioButton2.IsChecked == true)

            {                   
                cmbDrives.Text = "";

            }
```

but its not working

Comment: Are you trying to remove all of the items from `cmbDrives.Items` so that the list is empty or just reset the selection to the first item?[`Clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.clear?view=netframework-4.8) may be what you want.

Comment: I am trying to remove all the items so that it shows as empty. Not able to use Clear property for comboBox as its not available in my version

Comment: Sorry, I referenced the .NET documentation, not WPF. [`cmbDrives.Items.Clear()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.clear?view=netframework-4.8) has been supported for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use items.clear，but I think you just want to show nothing, if something is selected, try selecteditem=null, it may works

Comment: Maybe selectedtext?